# QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice python

Tags: python, pyqt

I import another Python module in my pyqt code file to get inputs and show output. but it gives me error

> QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

My code is:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from naivebase import *


class Main (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_clicked)
        self.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pushButton_clicked)
        # self.connect(QPushButton(), SIGNAL("clicked()"),  self.pushButton_clicked)

    def pushButton_clicked(self):
         text1 = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
         # print text1
         ob2 = TweetClassfier()
         txt = ob2.lbl1
         self.ui.label_2.setText(txt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have debugged the code it gives me this error after this line

```
QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
```

Comment: What is the contents of `naivebase`?

Comment: Naivbase is implementing a classifier using nltk

Comment: Can you edit your post to include 'naivebase'?

Comment: I'm guessing something you're importing (either `untitled` or `naivebase`) creates some kind of widget on import time.

Comment: two things: 1. You got an extra space on the line where you define `class Main(QtGui.QApplication)` (which is probably not there in the original code)

2. This is a longshot, but could there be a namespace conflict due to the import of all the names in `naivebase

Answer (score 1):

run this first and only once: 
    `app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)`

then run:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You already imported `QApplication` from `QtGui`. This means there is no need to reference `QtGui` in `app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)`.

Try: `app = QApplicatiopn(sys.argv)`

Edit: This is probably not the reason, though. Another guess is, as I commented above, to avoid importing `naivebase` with asterisk, which colludes your namespace and can lead to errors, e.g. if something else is called `app`.

Edit: In the end we can't really know for sure what is wrong without the contents of `untitled` (might wanna give this a meaningful name) and `naivebase`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of of `QMainWindow.__init__(self)`, try with `super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()`

That should work.

Also make sure naivebase and untitled don't have any code trying to instantiate QtGui objects in the main flow. Anything happening before the `QApplication()` call should be `def` and `class` stuff or pure-python stuff. By this I don't mean the classic `if __name__ == '__main__'`, but any other code or assignment in the file that is outside a def or class definition.